# Javascript append arrays to create nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

On a canvas I am capturing the mouse click coordinates, which I want to save as individual arrays...and with multiple click, want to create a nested array which contains multiple arrays for each click.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>parallelogram</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:solid 1px;margin:0;padding:0;"></canvas> 
   <p id="status"> | </p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
var items = [];
var image = "image.jpg";

function init(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = x+ "|" + y;
    items.push(image,x,y);
    console.log(items);
  })
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

</script>
```

However, I am getting new arrays getting appended to old array as continuous elements and not as arrays.  I tried with `push`, `push.apply`, `concat` etc., but they were not working.

The following is the output that I am getting for two subsequent clicks:

```
(6) ["image.jpg", 158, 194, "image.jpg", 254, 183]
```

Whereas the desired output is

```
[["image.jpg", 158, 194], ["image.jpg", 254,183]]
```

Comment: Push array instead of strings, update statement to `items.push([image,x,y]);` instead of `items.push(image,x,y);`

Comment: @HassanImam  Thank you for the super quick answer...

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to `items.push([image,x,y]);` and it works. Currently you are just pushing the `image`, `x` and `y` as a element of array. But doing `[image,x,y]` will push an array with elements `image`, `x` and `y`.

```js
var items = [];
var image = "image.jpg";

function init(){
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.innerHTML = x+ "|" + y;
    items.push([image,x,y]);
    console.log(items);
  })
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:solid 1px;margin:0;padding:0;"></canvas> 
   <p id="status"> | </p>
```